# Given a private SSH key, how do I recover my public key?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I've somehow lost my `id_rsa.pub` file. I still have my `id_rsa` file. How do I recover the public key from the private key?

(This question came up after `ssh-copy-id` was reporting "ERROR: No identities found" while `ssh-keygen` reported "/root/.ssh/id_rsa already exists". `ls ~/.ssh` pointed out the problem was having `id_rsa` but not `id_rsa.pub`. I found the solution, but it was buried at the bottom of a long post on an Ubuntu support forum.)

Comment: You can't just make another. OK I may [be wrong](http://www.lxg.de/code/restore-ssh-public-key)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can generate the public key using `ssh-keygen -y`. If your private key is in the default location, you can use the following to put the public key in the same place:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```